# How to write a datastructure to a file with fput in c?

Tags: c, fputs

What i have here is a struct that i want to print to a file. The structure consists of a series of singel character ints where pek3 Points at the first object containing a number in the structure.

fprintf didnt work and this just gives me the error:

missing ')' Before '->'

```
FILE *filen;
 int h;
            talstrul *tepek = pek3;
            filen = fopen("summadata.txt","w");
            for(h=1; h<=maxlen; h++)
            {   int fput(tepek->num,filen);
                tepek = tepek->next;
            }
            fclose(filen);
```

Comment: What is `fput`? That's not a standard function. Also what is the `int` doing on that line?

Comment: it says fput in my lecture notes, but i have tried fputs as well, and the int I supposed was because im gonna print an integer to the file?

Comment: you example needs more info to be relevant, e.g. how does the struct declaration look like, what is the expected content of the file you are writing to and so on.

Comment: Better show the declared structure, but just describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is incomplete - so we have to guess.

```
f = fopen("summadata.txt","w");
for(int h=1; h<=maxlen; h++) {
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", tepek->num);    
    tepek = tepek->next;
}
fclose(f);
```

should work.

`fprintf` works as follows:

- the first argument is the file handle, that is what you get from fopen.
- the format string, here "%d\n", describes, what you want to print. Here it is a integer ("%d") and then a newline ("\n").
- then comes the arguement(s) to the formatstring. In this case the integer, I guess that is `tepek->num`.

Comment: Sorry for the icompleteness, didnt want to make it confusing with too much code, Thanks alot! I guess i forgot the formatting parameter for fprintf when I tried to write to the file!! now the program works like a charm :D